# ATI propriatery drivers install latest 12.8, broke my kernel. Stuck on kernel 3.2.0-26

Tags: 12.04, grub2, ati, kernel, 64-bit

I messed up a bit. Hoping some here can help me.

I tried to install the newest catalyst 12.8. Sadly, this broke my system. I was stuck in low graphics mode. I finally managed to restore the proprietary drivers, and get into ubuntu again. But now I am stuck on kernel 3.2.0.26. I had installed kernel 3.2.0-30, but the system no longer sees it. I have kernel 3.2.0-29 too, but the system cannot see that as well. In the grub menu. When I use `sudo update-grub`, they are both listed.

Here are the output I get:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Cannot determine root device.  Assuming /dev/hda1
This error is probably caused by an invalid /etc/fstab
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

I have searched everywhere to find a solution to my problem, but can't find any solutions.

If you need any log outputs to figure out the problem, please let me know which ones.

Update: here is the output for grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=nb_NO
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-26-generic (gjenopprettelsesmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    echo    'Laster Linux 3.2.0-26-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-25-generic (gjenopprettelsesmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    echo    'Laster Linux 3.2.0-25-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (gjenopprettelsesmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    echo    'Laster Linux 3.2.0-24-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, med Linux 3.2.0-23-generic (gjenopprettelsesmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    echo    'Laster Linux 3.2.0-23-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 270c7c58-06d8-4e6b-b9bb-8d92f46adc0b
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 448AF3CE8AF3BA8E
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

How can I set kernel 3.2.0.30 as the default kernel? According to this file, kernel 3.2.0-30 does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Seems like my grub2 had reverted to grub. Reinstalled grub2, and the kernel was found. Back on kernel 3.2.0-30